# Creating a data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a barplot with a data frame which I made it. here is the code:

```
percentages_2000 <- c(3,21,23,26,28)
percentages_2015 <- c(2,22,21,29,27)
browser <- c("Opera", "Safari", "Firefox", "Chrome", "IE")
browsers <- data.frame(browser = browser, p_2000 = percentages_2000,
                   p_2015 = percentages_2015)
```

When I add the ggplot() and geom_bar(), it gives an error. What do I miss?
Error: stat_count() can only have an x or y aesthetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to `geom_col`like so.

```r
library(tidyverse)

percentages_2000 <- c(3, 21, 23, 26, 28)
percentages_2015 <- c(2, 22, 21, 29, 27)
browser <- c("Opera", "Safari", "Firefox", "Chrome", "IE")
browsers <- data.frame(
  browser = browser, p_2000 = percentages_2000,
  p_2015 = percentages_2015
)

bb <- browsers %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = percentages_2000:percentages_2015)


ggplot(bb, aes(browser, value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all for ggplot your data (almost always) has to be in a long format. To do this we run `browsers_melt = melt(browsers, id.vars = "browser")`

Then we run the following plotting code.

```
ggplot(browsers_melt, aes(x = browser, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge())
```